# OCI_PCONNECT opens new sessions for each call

Tags: php, connection-pooling, oracle-call-interface

I am retreiving some data from an oracle database from a php site using oci_pconnect.

The different between oci_pconnect and oci_connect as I could see is, oci_pconnect create sessions on the database, oci_connect not.

My problem is

On one server, when I refresh the same page several times. It creates for example for 10 refreshes appx 3 sessions. That means it uses the existing sessions as it is expected from pconnect.

On the other server, when I refresh the same page (getting data from the above mentioned db) several times. It creates for each refres a seperate session.

Is there a parameter in which I can manage the session opennings? I am expecting that it should use existing sessions and reduce connection time cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's supposed to be that way, ref: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57963